# How to use cosmos Tokenview API with postman？

Tags: rest, blockchain, cosmos

What is blockchain API and introduce tokenview.io blockchain explorer?

I want to use cosmos to get Tx information via blockchain explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://atom.tokenview.io/ query transaction records.
At the same time can also get an APIkey registration (https://services.tokenview.io/), after registration you can directly call API to get the data.
For example, to get a transaction, you can call this API directly:
https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/tx/atom/8AAE32278063143DBA59A34394550DB7547398EBAE75AF2EDB27B8CF95C87DCB? apikey={your apikey}.
It's very convenient.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6R90.png)